# Running yarn install returns syntax error

Tags: node.js, homebrew, node-modules, yarnpkg

I am new to Yarn. Whenever I run `yarn install` to install my dependencies, I get the following error in the `yarn-error.log` file:

```
Arguments: 
/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.7.0/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/bin/yarn.js install

PATH: 
 /Users/firstlastname/anaconda3/bin:/Users/firstlastname/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/firstlastname/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Yarn version: 
  1.22.4

Node version: 
  14.7.0

Platform: 
  darwin x64

Trace: 
  SyntaxError: /Users/firstlastname/Documents/01_projects/src/react-js/package.json: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 108
      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
      at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:1625:59
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at step (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:310:30)
      at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:321:13
```

I tried uninstalling Yarn with `brew uninstall node` and Node by clearing a Node version I had installed with the installer package from the nodejs.org website and reinstalling yarn + node with `brew install yarn`, but no awail.

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

EDIT, here's the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react-js",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://myname.github.io/storytelling",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "d3-scale": "^3.2.1",
    "mapbox-gl": "1.5.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "scrollama": "2.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "yarn build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: show us ```package.json``` file content, please.

Comment: I added the used `package.json` in the original post

Comment: Your JSON file length is 40 lines but log shows error on line 108. hmmm

Comment: Yes, I assumed the error is referring to something in `cli.js`  at `/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:1625:59` , as indicated in the error log?

Comment: remove node_modules folder and yarn.lock and retry ``` yarn ```

Comment: As suggested, I deleted the entire node_modules folder and the `yarn.lock` file but the error remains the exact same.

Comment: uninstall yarn with homebrew and install it using npm: ```npm i -g yarn```

Comment: after taking the above measures, I still receive the same error

Comment: try ```yarn cache clean``` then see what's happen after that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219640/discussion-between-emily-and-cybercoder).